# Setting up a Custom Cell in a Tableview with SWIFT

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to create a custom cell that will only be applied to one single CELL in a Section.

So a create a custom cass called buttonsTableViewCell, that is pretty much empty and only have one label called weightLabel() code bellow:

```
class buttonsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var weightLabel: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

On the Main.storyboard i connected everything:

[image: Setting the custom class]
[image: Connect the label to the class]
[image: Setting the identifier]

Now this is what i'm trying to do in the viewcontroller class, that controls the Tableview that has the cell.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

 var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell",   forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
          cell.textLabel?.text = "Testing"

if indexPath.row == 1 { // So it only changes this cell
  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("buttonsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as buttonsTableViewCell

  cell.weightLabel?.text = "Weight" // ERROR UITableViewCell does not have a member named 'weightLabel'
}

 return cell

}
```

What i'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift is statically typed language with type inference. So when you first assign the value of `cell` outside your if condition, the type of the cell variable is set to a normal `UITableViewCell`. 
Just use a different variable name like

```
if indexPath.row == 1 { 
    var buttonCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("buttonsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as buttonsTableViewCell

    buttonCell.weightLabel?.text = "Weight" 
    return buttonCell
}

var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell",   forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
cell.textLabel?.text = "Testing"

return cell
```

Comment: Hey Rakeshbs, thanks for the answer this actually worked, but i saw that you edited your answer, and for some reason if i do add the return buttonCell, it does not work anymore. Any ideas?